# Question regarding Connector

Tags: voltage, current, rf, connector, surface-mount

Can someone please help me to understand what type of connector is the below :

1. How do we classify this 99S12D-40MA5-y connector which is on page 33 in the [Catalog](https://www.rosenberger.com/0_documents/de/catalogs/ba_automotive/AUTO_HSD_Catalog_2017.pdf) document?

Do we call it as a contact type, male or female connector header or something else? I understand that it is not contact type since I have seen images of contact type connectors (connectors which don't have a locking mechanism). Can someone tell me what type of connector is that?

2. Can someone tell me also what type of connector is [this](https://products.rosenberger.com/radio-frequency/connectors/272096/d4s12h-40ma5-f-straight-plug-pcb-w.-housing)? What do they mean when they call the Gender of this connector as PLUG and what does the 40M signify? Please help to understand.

Answer (score 1):

To me, a plug has male contacts (pins).

In the specification table for that connector, the "Backend type" line indicates that "40M" is the manufacturer's code for that style of PCB-mounting connector.

Somewhere in the catalog there may be a description of how the connector part number is created - what all the bits of the number mean.

I don't understand what you mean by "contact connector" - that's not a term I have ever seen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me on what type can we call the above 2 connectors - Male/Female/others? And this is what I found on contact connector -https://www.google.com/search?q=contact+connector&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIN889IN889&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix4fnd4IHvAhXtwzgGHTmWAYYQ_AUI8AEoAQ&biw=1826&bih=886

Comment: @Newbie: the manufacturer calls it a plug - to me, that means it has male contacts.  Many of the connectors on that google page are made by a company called "Phoenix Contact", so the picture captions say "Phoenix Contact connectors - the illustrated connectors are not "contact connectors" - they are just connectors made by Phoenix Contact.  Any connector has contacts but that doesn't make them "contact connectors".

Comment: @Newbie:  Many connectors will be described as "[something]-contact connector" where [something] describes the type of contact.  Just plain "contact connector" is meaningless.